# Microsoft-Word: hide overflow in a table-cell

Tags: ms-word, document

I have a Word-File in which I'm going to add content programmatically. 
The content is going to be added into table-cells and thats where the problem starts:

The Word-File looks like this[image]

The cell where it now says "000000873588" is the one being filled by my application. This is working fine until someone enters a string thats too large like so:
[image]

The text is being broken down onto the next line which leads to my document actually adding a second page at the end because the whole content doesn't fit anymore.

Now I know the easiest way would be to already truncate the string in the application itself, but this would require me to know the exact cell-size of each cell in the document, which I don't as I have 12 different document-templates that are all being filled programmatically.

Is Word able to set a table-cell to a fixed size and then just cut off the overflow? I can't really imagine it not being able to. I did quite some research but the only thing I found was keeping cells together over page-breaks which is not what I need.

Comment: You can set the Row.Height to an exact size, which would cut off the *visibility* of anything that runs below that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already tried this, the problem with this solution is that you'd have to tune it JUST right so that when the text is in the invisible part, the top of the letters dont peak over the cell-border. And for 12 documents with loads of cells thats just impractical

Comment: That's the only possibility, as far as "cutting things" off is concerned. And too bad you didn't mention you'd already considered that so that no one would waste their time thinking about it and writing it up. Maybe you need to tell us what else doesn't work for you...

Comment: You're right of course. I'm sorry I didn't mention it earlier. Thats the only thing I found regarding cutting of text.

Comment: There is an option you can try out that fits text to cells by reducing font size (test in the Word UI in Table Properties, Cell tab I believe). Another possibility would be to format that column with Courier New (or any other non-proporitional font) so that you can calculate the accpetable width as a factor of the number of characters. Beyond that, you'd probably need to check and compare whether the document layout has changed (row moved to next page) after writing each cell value and remove characters until things fit, again.